# Cypress file upload

Tags: cypress

I have a "problem"

I'm  trying to upload a file in my cypress test, however my test runs with sucess but it doesn't upload.

I using the library cypress-file-upload;

```
my code:

const filePath = 'teste.pdf'

cy.get(':nth-child(1) > .backgroundColor > :nth-child(2) > :nth-child(1) > .col-auto > .input-group.mb-0 > .custom-file > .row > .form-group > .input-group > .input-group-text').attachFile(filePath)
```

result:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oAQL.png)

my html/css:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiRQm.png)

button:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zk99A.png)

ps: sorry for my bad english

I'm trying many css selector until xpath, but doesn't sucess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your target element in this case should be the `input` one.

Make sure `teste.pdf` is located at `fixtures` folder and try something like:

```js
const filePath = 'teste.pdf'

cy.get('.custom-file-input.form-control-sm.file-input').attachFile(filePath)
```